# How to publish a unity game on mobile without an error using WEBGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, 2d, unity-webgl

I need to publish the game made by unity with WEBGL, and wanna let the users play from mobile devices. I know unity does not officially support mobile devices on WEBGL, but would like to find a way to do it. It works just find on PC but getting this error on mobile devices. I appreciate your support in advance [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBuFD.jpg)

Comment: If you want to support mobile devices you should build for the native platform you want to support, iOS or Android.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually i would do that but my company wants to do a web service on mobile devices. Ive seen some people successfully publish it on mobile using webgl so Im trying to do so even though itd be complicated

Comment: Some 2d stuff does work. Have you tried it?

Comment: I turned out its a ios + unity issue not with the mobile devices